# What video game is this?

Tags: riddle, story, knowledge

> Four days ago, one of my seven brothers told me he had a riddle for me. 
>   He already told it to five of the others, but only two got the answer right, so I had to give it a try.
>   One thing I can tell is that he's crazy with video games, and indeed I had to find one of his favourite.
>   Now, january the 8th, I'm still puzzled. Five of my brothers already know the answer, and I'm feeling a bit stupid.
>   Here's the riddle, can you help me find the video game it is about?
>
> *There was a Guy, a Marine, a Slayer
>
>   Can you feel his anger?*
>
> *No arms, no legs, but not defenseless
>
>   I punch and I run nonetheless!*
>
> *First I wondered : are you Ken?
>
>   Then I knew : sure, you Ken!*
>
> *To pyramids, I want to go so bad
>
>   Two pyramids, some time ago I had*
>
> *I'm not her, stop saying that!
>
>   I'd rather be made fun of my hat*
>
> *Rushed and botched for Christmas season
>
>   Now resting in a desert, an abomination*
>
> *Melancholic island, crimson ashes
>
>   Captive until the prophecy unleashes*
>
> *Rise and fall, where human cultures lie
>
>   Always fear the little indian guy*
>
> *Radio noises in the fog, what do I hear?
>
>   A distant sound, now my worst fear*

Comment: Sentences 9 and 10 pretty much scream "Zelda".

Comment: [sure, you Ken!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-ZoZ1y1onQ) (possible spoiler)

Comment: Nice puzzle! Only criticism I'd have is that the story dressing is actually *part* of the puzzle, meaning the story doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Shouldn't the quote marks (`>`) start later?

Comment: Since the story is indeed part of the puzzle, I felt it was best to include it in the quote. How would you have formatted it ?

Comment: If the entire thing is quoted, it probably shouldn't be quoted at all. =) If the entire thing is quoted because it really is from someone else, then an external note about the source and giving credit is necessary (at which point, you now have an unquoted portion).

Comment: @jpmc26 - I'm not sure there's another way to easily convey that the intro story *is* part of the puzzle, rather than the usual framing that isn't.  Unquoting the whole thing wouldn't give that impression.

Comment: @jpmc26 I quoted the entire thing because it seems that every puzzle is put on a quote. If I unquoted the story well, Bobson is right on this, it would seem it isn't a part of the puzzle.

Comment: I *do* think quoting it was a good choice. But the *best* choice would be to not have the story be part of it at all, I think. (This is partially personal preference, though.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each couplet is a reference to a video game:

*There was a Guy, a Marine, a Slayer

Can you feel his anger?*

> DOOM: The protagonist is known as "Doom Guy", "Doom Marine", and "Doom Slayer".

*No arms, no legs, but not defenseless

I punch and I run nonetheless!*

> Rayman: Rayman (the protagonist of his eponymous video game series) has hands and feet that float rather than being connected to his body.

*First I wondered : are you Ken?

Then I knew : sure, you Ken!*

> Street Fighter: One of the characters' names is Ken, and a shoryuken ("Sure, you Ken!") is an attack in that game.

*To pyramids, I want to go so bad

Two pyramids, some time ago I had*

> Tomb Raider: The protagonist, Lara Croft, is known for exploring pyramids... and for her noticeably pyramidal breasts in the original character model. *(Thanks, Francesco Roggia!)*

*I'm not her, stop saying that!

I'd rather be made fun of my hat*

> The Legend of Zelda: The protagonist, Link, is known for his green hat, and often mistaken for Zelda based on the title.

*Rushed and botched for Christmas season

Now resting in a desert, an abomination*

> E.T. (for the Atari 2600): This is a reference to the infamous [Atari video game burial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_video_game_burial).

*Melancholic island, crimson ashes

Captive until the prophecy unleashes*

> Morrowind: explained in comments

*Rise and fall, where human cultures lie

Always fear the little indian guy*

> Civilization: the first line is a direct reference to the premise, and the second refers to a well-known bug where Gandhi would become extremely aggressive due to integer underflow.

*Radio noises in the fog, what do I hear?

A distant sound, now my worst fear*

> Silent Hill *(thanks, AmagicalFishy!)*

---

So what next?

> The intro text has a suspiciously large amount of numbers in it: 4, 1, 7, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8, 5. This is also the number of video games mentioned. Indexing into the video games by these numbers gives `MRFREE?AN`, which seems to say "Mr. Freeman". This would refer to [Gordon Freeman](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Gordon_Freeman), the protagonist of the **Half-Life** series.

Comment: I believe the "Radio noises" refers to Silent Hill, and, though I've never played it, does FarCry involve someone captive on an island fulfilling a prophecy?

Comment: @Saeïdryl We'd need something starting with M for "melancholic island" because of the indexing.

Comment: @Deusovi You're totally right, seems like I can't count properly :|

Comment: @Deusovi Solstheim first appearance is in Morrowind (I'm holding on). But the island was frozen at this time, so not really crimson ashes before Skyrim...

Comment: Maybe the pyramid part is a reference to Tomb Raider? She used to visit some kind of pyramids to raid tombs, and the first Lara Croft Characters had two "pyramids" as boobs

Comment: Myst? Monkey Island?

Comment: @Saeïdryl Vvardenfell, the main area of *Morrowind*, was volcanic, and far more ashy than Solstheim. Said ashes came from Red Mountain, hence crimson, perhaps? And *Morrowind* could easily be melancholic, and the main quest definitely involves a prophecy. But captive, particularly “until the prophecy unleashes”? Morrowind was a province of the Empire, and not happy with that situation, so that might be called “captive,” but they enjoyed full rights of citizenship rather than any second-class captive status, and in any event the province wasn’t liberated by the Nerevarine.

Comment: Fast answer, well done! And @Saeïdryl & KRyan do have a point...

Comment: @KRyan but you start the game as a prisoner, no?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Oh, true! And the “prophecy unleashes” could refer to the beginning of the prophecy (“In the waning years of the Third Era of Tamriel, a prisoner born on a certain day to uncertain parents was sent, under guard, without explanation, to Morrowind, ignorant of the role he was to play in that nation’s history.”) rather than its completion/fulfillment.

Comment: Definitely Morrowind. The majority of the island is covered in red ash. The protagonist is a prisoner shipped to the isle, who ultimately fulfils the prophecy of being lord Nerevar reborn, uniting the ash tribes and houses. Hence captive until the prophecy unleashes.